# why does the output of tolower() on a data table differ depending on how its applied?

Tags: r

Im using tolower() on a data table of all character type fields. When applied to the columns using differing syntax i get differing results, is this normal?

```
 tolower(tmp_dt[,1:5])
 "c(\"case\", \"student\", \"of\", \"case\", \"case\", \"week\", \"of\")\
 tolower(tmp_dt[,2])
 "case"    "student" "of"      "case"    "case"    "week"    "of"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to apply `tolower` on a `vector`.  According to the description in `?tolower`

> x - a character vector, or an object that can be coerced to character
>   by as.character.

If we check the `tolower`, it calls `as.character` and `as.character` expects a `vector` input

```
as.character(tmp_dt[1:2])
#[1] "c(\"Student\", \"Case\", \"OF\", \"OF\", \"OF\")"      
#[2] "c(\"week\", \"Student\", \"week\", \"week\", \"Student\")"
```

If we check `?as.character`

> Further, for as.character the default method calls as.vector, so
>   dispatch is first on methods for as.character and then for methods for
>   as.vector.

---

One way is to loop through the columns of the data.frame with `lapply`, apply the `tolower` and assign the output back to the data.frame columns

```
tmp_dt[, 1:5]  <- lapply(tmp_dt[,1:5], tolower)
tmp_dt
#       V1      V2      V3   V4   V5   V6
#1 student    week      of week case   OF
#2    case student student case   of Case
#3      of    week      of case   of   OF
#4      of    week      of   of case   OF
#5      of student student case case Case
```

---

If this is a `data.table`, then we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tmp_dt)[, (1:5) := lapply(.SD, tolower), .SDcols = 1:5]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
tmp_dt <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c('Case', 'Student', 'OF', 'week'),
          5*6, replace = TRUE), 5, 6), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: but then its returned as a list. I know that i can achieve the results i want with mapply, so i'm not really looking for a solution to getting the results in lower case, im wondering why it returns the results the way it does.

Comment: @Phi  Do you have a `data.frame` or `data.table`?  I updated both options and it works for me

Comment: `mapply(tolower,tmp_dt)` works on a data.table with a much cleaner syntax. I'm not trying to solve getting tolower to work. I want to understand WHY its returning data in the \"word\" format

Comment: @Phi It is already mentioned in my post that the `tolower` expects a vector and not a data.frame or data.table as input.  You can use `mapply` or lapply`, but `mappy` returns a `matrix` and it can create problems while `Map` is more or less the same as `lapply` output.  Anyway,

Comment: you're right about `mapply()` I should have said `as.data.table(tolower,tmp_dt)`. I see now what you mean as far as it expecting a vector. So it's not `tolower()` itself causing the differing outputs, its really a behavior of `as.character()`